# How can i get the #DIV/0! error to calculate?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

[image]I am trying to calculate the ratio between two numbers when one is  `0` .

Currently, this formula produces a blank cell, can anyone tweak it to allow it to calculate even if there is a  `0`  present?

This is the current formula :

`=IF(COUNT(E9)=0,IFERROR(AVERAGE(C9),""),IFERROR(SUM(C9/E9),""))`

Comment: Please note: `AVERAGE(C9)` is equivalent to `C9`. `SUM(C9/E9)` is equivalent to `C9/E9`. Don't use extra functions if you don't need to.

Comment: Please provide sample data and the expected output. Division by `0` is undefined so you need to define the result you want.

Comment: See edits, i want the w/l ratio to be calculated as 3.0

Comment: `=C9/IF(E9=0,1,E9)`. I gave you this formula before, right? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joining several comments into an answer:

- You can use `=C9/IF(E9=0,1,E9)` to divide by `1` if `E9` is equal to `0`.
- `AVERAGE(C9)` is equivalent to just `C9`; `SUM(C9/E9)` is equivalent to just `C9/E9`. It's best to avoid unnecessarily using extra functions.